# Backend API calls not rerouting in node express

Tags: node.js, angular, api, express, heroku

I've got two separate apps (frontend and backend) running on heroku. Let's say frontend can be accessed through `http://frontend-app.url` and backend through `http://backend-app.url` The front end app runs on `node.js` using `express`. I want my frontend app to call backend app api, but I can't make it call anything other than the same domain that frontend is deployed.

In `server.js` i got the following lines, which supposedly should reroute the api calls.

```
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    res.json({url: 'http://backend-app.url'})
});
```

All api urls start with `/data`. I start my app by `node server.js`.
First call when accessing the frontend app is always `/data/units`, but it always calls `http://frontend-app.url/data/units` instead of `http://backend-app.url/data/units`.

How do I make this right?

Comment: `res.json` does not reroute. It simply converts the response to JSON and sends it back. See [res.json](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json). Have you looked at [res.redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) ?

Comment: Did some more research after looking into Mayur's comment and found the answer on a different SO question. So marking this as duplicate.